# Div fica cortado quando altera o tamanho da janela + css

Tags: css, div

Pessoal não sei como procurar isso na web, até que formular a pergunta está dificil, o que acontece é que tenho uma div na tela com background=red por exemplo, a tela estando expadida fica beleza, quando eu dou um resize na tela e volto pra maximizada o div não acompanha e fica cortado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver?
Já tentei width 100%, auto etc...

Comment: Estás a usar JavaScript para definir a largura? Podes criar um exemplo aqui ou no jsFiddle?

Comment: Poderia colocar um pouco do seu código ou até mesmo criar no jsFiddle como o Sergio sugeriu?

Comment: Liste-nos o código para que possamos te ajudar, pode ser hierarquia de DIV ou o próprio width, classes responsivas e etc. Precisamos ver o código.

Comment: Segue um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=U9N7rS3HQd